# Remove Special Characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am convert paragraph into words it contains many special characters like

```
"  , "  . `
```

how to remove this characters in nsstring and get only alphabets in nsstring

ex
"new" to new `//the special characters are change`

Comment: http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=73

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
NSString *unfilteredString = @"!@#$%^&*()_+|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[unfilteredString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Result: %@", resultString);
```

TRY THIS IT MAY HELPS YOU

Comment: Result Gives you Only alphabets

Comment: It does not work for non EN characters. Use `alphanumericCharacterSet` instead hardcoded string.

Comment: Make sure you use your own string instead of `unfilteredString`, else it will indeed give you only alphabets.

Answer (score 5):

There are numerous ways of dealing with this.  As an example, here's a solution using regular expressions.  This is just an example.  We don't know the entire range of special characters that you want to remove.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[,\\.`\"]"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                      error:NULL];
        NSString *sampleString = @"The \"new\" quick brown fox, who jumped over the lazy dog.";
        NSString *cleanedString = [expression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:sampleString
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, sampleString.length)
                                                                  withTemplate:@""];
        printf("cleaned = %s",[cleanedString UTF8String] );

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Per comment of @Rostyslav Druzhchenko from on the selected answer of @MadhuP:

```
NSString *unfilteredString = @"!@#$%^&*()_+|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSString *escapedString = [[unfilteredString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Result: %@", escapedString);
```

This is the answer that will use `alphanumericCharacterSet` to handle multiple countries character set.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer in SWIFT (but not SWIFTY way):

```
 let notAllowedCharactersSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ").invertedSet
 let filtered = (stringToFilter.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(notAllowedCharactersSet) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
```

Comment: How about the way for C++, Java, Python, Bourne-again shell, awk, and MEL?

Comment: @Droppy Because we are talking about NSFoundation objects, that are only available in Obj-C and Swift languages.

Comment: So C and C++ count then?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but for anyone trying to do this in Swift, here's what I did to make sure there were no special characters in my users' phone numbers.

```
var phone = "+1 (555) 555 - 5555"
var removeChars: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890").invertedSet
var charArray = phone.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(removeChars)
var placeholderString = ""
var formattedPhoneNumber: String = placeholderString.join(charArray).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

The `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` might not be necessary.