# How to transfer uncertain character such as "( " in regular expression?

Tags: objective-c, regex

```
 NSString *yourString = @"/Users/user/Downloads/data(1).txt.download/data(1).txt";
        NSError *error = NULL;
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                      regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/Users/user/Downloads/data(1).txt-*\\d*.download"
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                      error:&error];
        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
            // your code to handle matches here
            NSLog(@"%@ %ld",match,flags);
        }];
```

Refer to the code above, when there is special character `"("` in the file name, it can not be matched because regularExpression should use `"\\("`, ofCourse i can use `@"/Users/user/Downloads/data\\(1\\).txt-*\\d*.download"` to match, but how about when the file name contains other special characters. Is there any way to handle with this scenario in a common way?

The parameter `regularExpressionWithPattern` should be a variable with `[NSString stringWithFormat:xxx]`

Comment: you can remove "(" such special character before comparison ..

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13430545/1308632

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to handle with this scenario in a common way?

Why not solve the problem with a regular expression (RE)? I.e. before using a string which you wish to match as-is as part of a pattern apply a RE to the string which matches any RE metacharacters and add the required escape.

E.g. the pattern `[()]` will match an open or a close parenthesis and you can replace any match with `\\` followed by itself.

HTH